# Spring Data Jpa Query Generation: `IgnoreCase` not working with `exists`

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I the following repository:

```
interface MyRepository extends CrudRepository<MyType, String> {

  boolean existsByRealmAndClientCodeIgnoreCase(String realm, String clientCode)

}
```

It's working great except, it's case sensitive.

All the examples I find for the use of the `IgnoreCase` clause in the documentation is for `find` methods and not `exists` methods.

Could it be that spring-data-jpa forgot implement the `IgnoreCase` functionality for `exists`?

Comment: you might be looking for `existsByRealmIgnoreCaseAndClientCodeIgnoreCase`

Comment: This worked great! If you make this an answer, I'll accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `IgnoreCase` suffix only affects the attribute it is attached to, not the complete query. 
So you probably want

```
boolean existsByRealmIgnoreCaseAndClientCodeIgnoreCase(
        String realm, 
        String clientCode
)
```

Or the shorter form

```
boolean existsByRealmAndClientCodeIgnoreCaseAll(
        String realm, 
        String clientCode
)
```

Comment: Also, I discovered that `existsByRealmAndClientCodeIgnoreCaseAll` is an option.